# Make IN clause behave like AND clause

Tags: postgresql, relational-division

I've asked the same question on [stackoverlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25423731/active-record-relation-and-filtering), but got no answer, so that's why I'm asking it here (I've read that simple sql questions should be asked at SO, but I have no choice).

Suppose I have 3 tables: `posts`, `post_categories` and `categories`. I'm implementing some kind of page with filters where I can filter posts by categories. User can select multiple categories. When he selects more than one, they should be summed. I can't get it working. What I have now is simple `IN()` SQL clause:

```
SELECT posts.id, post_categories.category_id FROM posts 
JOIN post_categories ON posts.id = post_categories.post_id 
WHERE post_categories.category_id IN (1,2,3) LIMIT 10;
```

But it is not matching all ids, it is `OR` and I need `AND`. What I need here is to find all posts that have categories with `id=1 AND id=2 AND id=3`, but instead this query returns posts that have at least one category from the `IN()` list.

Comment: You did not specify whether `(post_id, category_id)` is unique in `post_categories`. Daniel assumes as much for his query. Here is a fiddle with all three queries provided so far: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6f12f/1

Comment: For what it's worth, I would go with @Craig's answer https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/74684/2639

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `IN()` operator is equivalent to a series of `OR`, which doesn't help you at all here.

Instead, I would build the query in a manner like this.

```
SELECT posts.id
FROM posts 
WHERE posts.id IN (SELECT post_id FROM post_categories WHERE category_id=1) AND
      posts.id IN (SELECT post_id FROM post_categories WHERE category_id=2) AND
      posts.id IN (SELECT post_id FROM post_categories WHERE category_id=3)
```

Admittedly, not a pretty construct, but I wrote it for readability. The following query might perform better:

```
SELECT posts.id
FROM posts
-- include:
WHERE posts.id IN (
        SELECT post_id
        FROM post_categories
        WHERE category_id IN (1, 2, 3)
        GROUP BY post_id
        HAVING COUNT(*)=3)
-- exclude:
    AND posts.id NOT IN (
        SELECT post_id
        FROM post_categories
        WHERE category_id NOT IN (1, 2, 3))
```

The second query assumes that the primary key of `post_categories` is `(post_id, category_id)`. Since you haven't specified which rdbms you're running, you may have to tweak my code a bit to make it run.

*Edit*: The `-- exclude:` part eliminates posts that have any other category_id than 1, 2 or 3. You may want to skip this part depending on if you want to return a) all posts that have categories 1, 2 and 3 or b) all posts that have exactly categories 1, 2 and 3 and no other categories.

Answer (score 5):

`IN` is like writing `= ANY`, e.g.

```
regress=> SELECT 1 = ANY (ARRAY[1, 2, 3]);
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

A simplistic interpretation of your question would be to say that you're asking for `= ALL`, but that rarely makes sense:

```
regress=> SELECT 1 = ALL (ARRAY[1, 2, 3]);
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

What you *really want* is to *find all `posts` that have a corresponding `post_categories` entry for each of a listed set of `category_id`*.

As is usual in relational databases, as soon as you clearly frame the question, the solution starts writing its self.

You could do a multiple join, like Daniel suggests, but that's a pain because it requires dynamic SQL. Or you could use relational set operations.

Instead, I'd possibly use PostgreSQL's array features. This would be easier if you'd provided *sample data*, but I think you want something like the following, which finds each category that matches the post then does a check to see if all the categories match (the `HAVING` clause):

```
SELECT
   posts.id
FROM posts 
INNER JOIN post_categories ON posts.id = post_categories.post_id 
WHERE post_categories.category_id IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY posts.id
HAVING array_agg(post_categories.category_id) @> ARRAY[1,2,3]
LIMIT 10
```

Untested, since you didn't provide sample data in `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT`s form, but that's the general idea. [`@>` means "array-contains"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html); I suspect it'll be more efficient than using `array_agg(category_id ORDER BY category_id)` and an equality test against a sorted `ARRAY` literal, because you avoid the sort on aggregation.

You could leave out the `WHERE` clause and this would still work, but it might be quite slow, as it'd fail to filter out posts in which *none* of the categories matched before doing aggregation.

BTW, `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is usually a bug. The database can return any set of 10 matching results it feels like, in any order.

Answer (score 4):

Most importantly, this is a special case of **relational division**. Once you know the name of the beast you'll find plenty of query techniques. Like the arsenal we assembled on SO:

- [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation/7774879#7774879)

Building on this test case (which you should have provided):

```
CREATE TABLE post (
   post_id serial PRIMARY KEY
 , post text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE category (
   category_id serial PRIMARY KEY
 , category text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE post_category (
   post_id int REFERENCES post
 , category_id int REFERENCES category
 , PRIMARY KEY (post_id, category_id)
);
```

<sup>Since I have to provide my own test case I am using proper table and column names. I prefer singular terms for table names where each row represents a single entity. And I avoid the unhelpful `"id"` as column name.</sup>

The special requirement in your case is to make it work with a **dynamic set of categories**, I suggest **two nested `EXISTS` anti-semi-joins**. Should be the fastest and IMO also most elegant way.

This is the task how I understand it after reading the question a couple of times:

*"Find all posts that have all of the given categories attached."*
Which can be expressed in its inverted form:
*"Find all posts where none of the given categories is missing."*

Short form with given set of `category_id`:

```
SELECT p.*                                   -- "Find all posts ..."
FROM   post p
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (                          -- "where none of the ..."
   SELECT 1
   FROM  (VALUES (1),(2),(3)) c(category_id) -- "given categories ..."
   WHERE  NOT EXISTS (                       -- "is missing"
      SELECT 1
      FROM   post_category pc
      WHERE  pc.post_id = p.post_id
      AND    pc.category_id = c.category_id
      )
   );
```

Or, retrieving IDs from the `category` table first:

```
-- posts with red & green
SELECT p.*
FROM   post p
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   category c
   WHERE  c.category IN ('red', 'green') -- retrieve IDs from cat table
   AND    NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM   post_category pc
      WHERE  pc.post_id = p.post_id
      AND    pc.category_id = c.category_id
      )
   );
```

[**SQL Fiddle** demonstrating all.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ad8bc/1)

Answer (score 3):

***SCOPES*** can help your out for this.....for example:-

**in post**

```
 has_many :post_categories
 has_many :categories
scope :recent_posts, where('created_at < ?', 1.days.ago).order('created_at ASC').limit(10)
scope :recent_posts_with_good_categories, includes(:post_categories).where("post_categories.name=?", "GOOD").merge(Post.recent_post)
scope :recent_posts_with_bad_categories, includes(:post_categories).where("post_categories.name=?", "BAD").merge(Post.recent_post)
scope :recent_posts_with_good_bad__evil_categories, includes(:post_categories).where("post_categories.name in ?", ["GOOD","BAD","EVIL"]).merge(Post.recent_post)


####similarly you can add multiple scopes in other models using includes and merge to get summed results
```

**in post_category**

```
 belongs-to :post
 has_many :categories
```

#### similar scopes can come here as well

**in category**

```
     belongs-to :post
     belongs-to :post_category
###similar scopes can come here as well
```

**the same can be achieved using class methods and chain them the way u want:-**

```
t=params[:categories_id]

    def self.find_users_with_categories(t)
      ##here you can query with all associated models as they are included
      Post.all(:joins => :post_categories,:categories, :select => "posts.*,categories.name",:group => "posts.id").where("categories.id IN (?)",t)           
      end
```

Comment: `IN` is still `OR` behavior and a I need `AND` — I need to query all posts which only have *all* of the categories that user chooses.