# How to select rows each having all of the specified tags?

Tags: postgresql

This is the table containing `hytags_hyobjects` that are tagged with `hytags_tags`

```
                                                Table "public.hytags"
       Column        |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                  Default                  
---------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------
 hytags_id           | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('hytags_hytags_id_seq'::regclass)
 hytags_datecreated  | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 hytags_datemodified | timestamp without time zone |           |          | 
 hytags_usercreated  | text                        |           | not null | CURRENT_USER
 hytags_usermodified | text                        |           | not null | CURRENT_USER
 hytags_hyobjects    | integer                     |           | not null | 
 hytags_tags         | integer                     |           | not null | 
 hytags_description  | text                        |           |          |
```

I would like to get `hytags_hyobjects` having all of the tag integers, such as 1, 2, 3 in `hytags_tags` where those values come from multiple rows. Selecting those that have either one of the tags is easy. I am looking to select those `hytags_hyobjects` which have all of the tags assigned.

Comment: Please provide your table structures and some sample data plus your desired output in a fiddle (dbfiddle.uk) - post the same data here. Also, **always** include your version of PostgreSQL in your questions. A+!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make IN clause behave like AND clause](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74643/make-in-clause-behave-like-and-clause)

Comment: By following the example in the duplicate I have solved it with: `SELECT DISTINCT hytags_hyobjects FROM hytags WHERE hytags_hyobjects IN (SELECT hytags_hyobjects FROM hytags WHERE hytags_tags = 191) AND hytags_hyobjects IN (SELECT hytags_hyobjects FROM hytags WHERE hytags_tags = 867)` where by without `DISTINCT` I would get duplicates.